# How to assert a JSON node has child nodes with certain values assigned to them?

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I have a JSON String like the following:

```
json =  "{\"Things\": \n" +
    "    {\"Thing\": {\n" +
    "        \"ID\":\"123\",\n" +
    "        \"name\":\"Yet Another Thing\",\n" +
    "        \"price\":\"$12.99\",\n" }\n" +
    "    }\n" +
    "}";
```

Is there a way I can assert that the `ID` of `Thing` is `123` *AND* that it's `name` is "`Yet Another Thing`" in *the same* statement/assert?

At the moment, I seem to fail using filters:

```
JsonPath.read(json, "$.Things.Thing[?(@.ID == '123')].name")
```

I get the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid container object

Is that maybe because thereis no array notation `[]` in the JSON string above? Should there be?

On a related note, is there a good introduction to using Hamcrest (with JSON assert)? I know the official tutorial, but I always seem to get it wrong...

UPDATE: The rational for this was: what if I get several `Thing` elements back, about whose order I have no guarantee (so I can't match `Thing[1]` (unless I looped through them all))? How do I make sure one element has both, the right ID and the right name? If I check for the children separately, don't I run the risk that one `Thing` has the right name and another the right ID, but none has both? (Would that be possible with that JSON format, or would I have to an array in that case anyway, like `"Thing": [ { ... }, { ... } ], ...` ?

<sup>P.S.: I tried to use the JsonPath above as follows in the end: `assertEquals("Yet Another Thing", JsonPath.read(json, "$.Things.Thing[?(@.ID == '123')].name"));`
So that's where the exception might have come from, too. Also, I initially asked this question on the JsonPath mailing list, but didn't get any replies so far, so was hoping I might get help here quicker... :)</sup>

Comment: Why one statement only? You can use several... You can also use a JSON Schema, or JSON Pointer

Comment: Why not just `Map things = parsedJson.getMap("Things"); Map thing = things.getMap("Thing"); if (things.getString("ID").equals("123")) { name = things.getString("name"); }`/

Comment: @fge: I suppose I was thinking: what if I get several `Thing` elements back (about whose order I have no knowledge/guarantee). I want to make sure that I don't have a situation where one has the right ID and another has the right name, but none has both. Does that make sense? And as someone who has never worked with JSON before: could that happen here anyway, or would that require an array like so: `"Thing": [ { ... }, { ... } ], ...` ?

Comment: Are you working with a defined API? Is this your own? And if you wonder about this, the behaviour of a JSON parser if an object has duplicate keys is undefined, so yes, an array would be needed in this case

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial gives the solution to your problem, it seems:

```
JsonAssert.with(json).assertThat("$.Things.Thing.ID", Matchers.equalTo("123"))
    .assertThat("$.Things.Thing.name", Matchers.equalTo("Yet Another Thing"));
```